# How request.getHeader("referer") works with Forward and Redirects?

Tags: servlets

I have a servlet. I am hitting this servlet as `http://someDomain/MyServlet/URLPattern`.
In `doGet` method of this servlet I am forwarding to a JSP 
page present under WEB-INF folder. Below is the code,

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

In index.jsp page, am hitting another URL(servlet) using `POST` method.

In `doPost` method of the target servlet, am getting the `referer` using `request.getHeader("referer"))`

This prints the value as

`http://someDomain/MyServlet/URLPattern`

I thought it would return `http://someDomain/../index.jsp` since this was the 
actual point at which trigger was made to the target URL.

I want to understand this behavior. If some one can get answer with authorized source
where it explains the behavior, it would be of great help.

Above question was with the behavior for `forward`. What would be the behavior 
for `sendRedirect` and what value would `referer` hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A forward happens completely at server-side, and the browser doesn't know and care about it.

A forward is just like an internal method call in your server-side logic. So, you're at the URL `http://someDomain/MyServlet/URLPattern`, and multiple server-side components (a servlet, a JSP) are used to answer the unique GET request sent by the browser, to the URL `http://someDomain/MyServlet/URLPattern`.

The only thing the browser knows is that it sent a GET request to this URL, and got a response back. So the referrer of the next request will be this URL.

To make an analogy, let's say you buy a book at Amazon, and I ask you: where did you buy that book? You'll answer "at Amazon", and not "at the room #453 of the San Francisco stockroom #5 of Amazon, because that's none of your business: only Amazon knows that. You bought a book at Amazon, and got the book. What Amazon did internally to send you the book is unknown.

In this story, you are the browser, and Amazon is the server.

`sendRedirect()` is completely different. You send a first request to the server, which uses sendRedirect() to wend you an HTTP response containing a `Location` header pointing to another URL. The browser then sends a second request to this other URL.

Comment: So, if I had used `sendRedirect()`, I would have got `referer` as `http://someDomain/../index.jsp` ?

Comment: Yes, but you should not do that. First because it wouldn't work: JSPs placed under WEB-INF are not acessible from the outside. Second because JSPs should not receive requests directly. The requests should go through a controller (servlet), and the controller should forward to a view (the JSP), whose responsibility is to generate markup using the model prepared by the controller. In general, using the referred header is a bad idea. You shouldn't care where the request comes from, and some browsers won't send the referrer header anyway.